# Is there any way to check if different formats of the same header is supported in postman tests?

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I have requests that require a token. Its passed in the header for the request as a key value pair with the key being access_token and the value being its value. Now different formats of the access token needs to be supported. eg: AccessToken,Access-Token,Access_Token. Is there any way I can verify it?[image: As shown in the attachment, I need to write a test case to check whether all these different variations are supported one by one.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up two arrays as environment variable :

```
pm.environment.set("header",["access","acces2","access3","aaccess4"])

pm.environment.set("header_temp",["access","acces2","access3","aaccess4"])
```

After that delete the above lines from script and below line to your pre-request script:

replace **pass_2** with the request name you are trying

```
pm.environment.get("header_temp").length === pm.environment.get("header").length ? pm.environment.set("header", pm.environment.get("header_temp")) : null

let header = pm.environment.get("header")
let header_temp = pm.environment.get("header_temp")

if (header.length !== 1) {
    console.log(header.length)
    pm.environment.set("token", header.pop())
    pm.environment.set("header", header)
    postman.setNextRequest("pass_2")
    console.log("pass_2")
} else {
    
     pm.environment.set("token", header.pop())
     pm.environment.set("header", header_temp)
    postman.setNextRequest(null)
    console.log("null")
}
```

Set header as a variable token:

[image]

Now open collection runner and run it , you can see that single request was send 4 times with those 4 headers

You can try below collection that I created:

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/7288ea50c0eca2ebf115